# Alter file.show() behaviour

Tags: r, file-io, rstudio

I'm running `file.show()` in RStudio on a Mac, like this:

```
filename <- "/Users/me/reports/myfile.pdf" # replace with file location/name
file.show(file.path(filename), title="My File")
```

This does two things:

1. Opens my file.pdf
2. Opens a blank file in RStudio called "My File".

   ```
   options()$pdfviewer
   ```

returns:

```
"/usr/bin/open"
```

How can I stop (2) from happening?

Comment: You need to specify more of what your working environment is. For instance, what does this return: `options()$pdfviewer`. I get different behavior in a Mac (but not running RStudio.)

Comment: question updated with out of `options()$pdfviewer`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply open a PDF file via RStudio on a Mac, the simplest way (as far as I know) is to use the `system` function:

```
filename <- "/Users/me/reports/myfile.pdf"
pdf <- getOption("pdfviewer") # same as options()$pdfviewer
cmd <- paste(pdf,filename)
system(cmd)
```

For example it is used by `openPDF` in Biobase (see [here](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/Biobase/html/openPDF.html))

I don't know a way to alter the `file.show` behaviour in order to prevent a blank file being opened in RStudio. I think it has something to do with *`The R.app Mac OS X GUI uses its internal pager irrespective of the setting of pager.`* that you can see on the manual [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/file.show.html).

Note: it is different on a Windows machine, use `shell.exec(filename)` directly.